# Extracting Data From Webpage That Isn't In the Source Code

Tags: javascript, excel, dom, vbscript

I'd like to write a macro in Excel that pulls data from the webpage below:

http://www.richmond.com/data-center/salaries-virginia-state-employees-2013/?appSession=673718284851033&RecordID=101177&PageID=3&PrevPageID=2&cpipage=1&CPIsortType=&CPIorderBy=&cbCurrentRecordPosition=1

The problem I'm having is that the employee information data isn't in the page source so when I use the code below (where NextPage is set to the above URL) the `responseText` doesn't include the data I'm looking for.

```
With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", NextPage, False
    .Send
    htm.body.innerHtml = .responseText
End With
```

I could very well be wrong but I believe the data is contained within the page's DOM. Can someone help me understand how I can download the contents of this page as displayed (i.e. after the javascript modifications have been applied) using VBScript?

Comment: You might get better answers if you told us what data you're actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object should give you access to the actual DOM tree:

```
url = "http://www.richmond.com/..."

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

ie.Navigate url

Do
  WScript.Sleep 100
Until ie.ReadyState = 4

Set elem = ie.Document.getElementById("...")
```

If that doesn't work, you may have to resort to something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. I will try this when I get back to my computer on Monday. Your earlier comment about providing more detail is well taken. I'm looking to build a macro that I can use to pull the first name, last name, base salary, and hire date from each individual employee profile put it in a row in Excel and then continue to the next employe profile, pull the same data, and then repeat for every employee. There are many thousands of employees which is why I'm trying to find a way to automate this process of extracting data. Thanks again for your response.